# foreach array than search in other array

Tags: php

Why this doesn't work? if (array_search((string)$key,$list))

```
foreach ($head as $index => $key) 
        {
                if (array_search((string)$key,$list))
                {
                    $data[$index] = serialize($data[$index]);
                    $combined[$key] = isset($data[$index]) ? $data[$index] : null;
                } else {

                    $combined[$key] = isset($data[$index]) ? $data[$index] : null;
                }

        }
```

$list is an array to search in

Comment: And what happens? what doesn't work?

Comment: this doesn't work: if (array_search((string)$key,$list))

Comment: Just a note, array_search will return the key of the matching element, if the matching element is at key 0, then your if will evaluate it as false and jump into the else.

Comment: If you don't need to extract key, you can change array_search to in_array(). print_r() your arrays so we can diagnose problem.

Comment: $list - Array ( [d_name] => ad_attr2 ) 
$head - Array ( [1] => user_id [2] => ad_ref [3]  [26] => date_created [27] => ad_attr1 [28] => ad_attr2 [29] => ad_attr3 [30] => ad_attr4 [31] => ad_attr5 [32] =>)

Comment: if(in_array((string)$key, $list)) not working as well

Answer (score 1):

Info from php.net:

> array_search — Searches the array for
>   a given value **and returns the
>   corresponding key** if successful
>   http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

try:

```
if($newKey = array_search((string)$key, $list))
```

By the way, you will get an notice on "`$data`", `$data` is not defined.

Br,
Paul Peelen

Comment: Can you add more of your code or a link to a phps file or something? Update your question with the full code so its easy to read. /P